# Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter setSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I used `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to navigate between fragments with the same layout. In a fragment's `onActivityCreated()`, I set the activity's action bar to the current fragment's toolbar. The problem is that the viewpager pre-loads fragments since off-screen page limit is set to 2 which makes all but the last `setSupportActionBar()` calls invalid. Any help?

I know that I can keep references to all current active pages and call `setSupportActionBar()` in `onPageSelected()` instead. But that considered a bad practice, right?

**Update:** Just confirmed that even use `WeakReference`, the fragments still won't get freed.

Answer (score 0):

One way around is to use `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` Fragment's method and there to set the Toolbar.

Also you can attach `OnPageChangeListener` on your ViewPager and update the toolbar when the page is selected.

Comment: For the former solution, I googled that `setUserVisibleHint()` is called before `onCreateView()` and I can confirm that pre-loaded fragments also call `onCreateView()` before they become visible to the user. The order of which  fragment calls first is unpredictable. For the second solution, isn't it bad to interfere in fragment management?